A very unlucky man followed by a reporter
Me and my coworker were discussing comedic movies and he then described a movie about a man who is extremely unlucky, so unlucky a reporter takes note of him and decides to follow him around. he also mentions a specific scene:
The unlucky man goes to a restaurant and the reporter decides to place 2 salt dispensers on his table, 1 with a loose lid, and one in good conditions, he does this without the unlucky person noticing. He then sits back at another table and watches the man as he gets his soup.
The man grabs the right salt dispenser (the one with the fastened lid) and the reporter was surprised but then the moment the unlucky man wanted to use the salt someone on an other table asked if he could borrow 1 dispenser since he had none and the unlucky man gives him the dispenser he has in his hand. Obviously now the unlucky man takes the one with the loose lid and the report is amazed at how unlucky this man actually is.
Some details about the scene might be wrong, but that's about what happened. we both have no idea what the name of this movie is but i very much would like to see it, if it's as funny as my coworker says.
Any idea what movie this might be? and is it as funny as I'm made to believe?

This is either the french film La Chèvre, or its american remake Pure Luck. (it's been a long time since I've seen either of them, but I think the scene with the salt happens in both films). - There are trailers for both films on Youtube: La Chèvre, Pure Luck

If you are interested in Bollywood movies here is a movie with the same scene the only thing is instead unlucky man there is unlucky girl. :D
Movie name is 'Action Jackson'. Enjoy :)
